# Increasing Mouse-key acceleration

Tags: keyboard

I've searched around, but I cannot find anything telling me how to adjust the mouse-key speed. Is there a menu I'm missing, or a command I can type in to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly open a terminal window and type the following to install the xkbset package:

```
sudo apt-get install xkbset
```

A simple one line command can then be used to configure the acceleration:

```
xkbset ma [delay] [interval] [time to max] [max speed] [curve]
```

For those new to command-line interfaces, the brackets imply that they need to be replaced by a numerical value, tailored to suite a particular use. I have recently used the following for my configuration:

```
xkbset ma 60 10 10 20 10
```

Comment: how to make it persistent